# C++ Struct to Byte* throwing error

Tags: c++, serialization, struct

I have attached my code below. I do not see what I am doing wrong. I have a struct that I am trying to serialize into a byte array. I have wrote some some simple code to test it.  It all appears to work during runtime when I print out the values of objects, but once I hit return 0 it throws the error:

***Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'command' was corrupted.***

I do not see the issue. I appreciate all help.

```
namespace CommIO
{
    enum Direction {READ, WRITE};

    struct CommCommand
    {
        int command;
        Direction dir;
        int rwSize;
        BYTE* wData;

         CommCommand(BYTE* bytes)
        {
            int offset = 0;
            int intsize = sizeof(int);

            command = 0;
            dir = READ;
            rwSize = 0;

            memcpy(&command, bytes + offset, intsize);
            offset += intsize;
            memcpy(&dir, bytes + offset, intsize);
            offset += intsize;
            memcpy(&rwSize, bytes + offset, intsize);
            offset += intsize;

            wData = new BYTE[rwSize];
            if (dir == WRITE)
            {   
                memcpy(&wData, bytes + offset, rwSize);
            }
        }

        CommCommand() {}
    }

int main()
{
    CommIO::CommCommand command;
    command.command = 0x6AEA6BEB;
    command.dir = CommIO::WRITE;
    command.rwSize = 128;
    command.wData = new BYTE[command.rwSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < command.rwSize; i++)
    {
        command.wData[i] = i;
    }

    command.print();

    CommIO::CommCommand command2(reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&command));
    command2.print();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the size of `Direction` is the same as the size of an `int`.  That may indeed be the case, but C++ does not guarantee it.

Comment: You also seem to be assuming that the members of `CommIO::CommCommand` will be laid out in memory without any padding between, which again may happen to be the case, but is not guaranteed.

Comment: Think about the difference between `wData` and `&wData`. Which one is the address of the buffer you just allocated?

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ Serialization".  Your process is called "serialization".

Comment: @JohnBollinger will the #pragma pack() directives help with this?

Comment: @Agallen90, depending on your C++ compiler and on exactly how you apply `#pragma pack`, you might that way avoid padding between members.  That is inherently non-portable.  Packing does nothing for the possible mismatch between the size of `Direction` and the size of `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following points mentioned in comments are most likely the causes of your problem.

1. You seem to be assuming that the size of `Direction` is the same as the size of an `int`. That may indeed be the case, but C++ does not guarantee it.
2. You also seem to be assuming that the members of `CommIO::CommCommand` will be laid out in memory without any padding between, which again may happen to be the case, but is not guaranteed.

There are couple of ways to fix the that.

1. Make sure that you fill up the `BYTE` array in the calling function with matching objects, or
2. Simply cast the `BYTE*` to `CommCommand*` and access the members directly.

For (1), you can use:

```
int command = 0x6AEA6BEB;
int dir = CommIO::WRITE;
int rwSize = 128;

totatlSize = rwSize + 3*sizeof(int);
BYTE* data = new BYTE[totalSize];

int offset = 0;
memcpy(data + offset, &comand, sizeof(int));
offset += sizeof(int);
memcpy(data + offset, &dir, sizeof(int));
offset += sizeof(int);
memcpy(data + offset, &rwSize, sizeof(int));
offset += sizeof(int);

for (int i = 0; i < rwSize; i++)
{
   data[i + offset] = i;
}

CommIO::CommCommand command2(data);
```

For (2), you can use:

```
CommCommand(BYTE* bytes)
{
   CommCommand* in = reinterpret_cast<CommCommand*>(bytes);

   command = in->command;
   dir = in->dir;
   rwSize = in->size;

   wData = new BYTE[rwSize];
   if (dir == WRITE)
   {   
      memcpy(wData, in->wData, rwSize);
   }
}
```

The other error is that you are using

```
memcpy(&wData, bytes + offset, rwSize);
```

That is incorrect since you are treating the address of the variable as though it can hold the data. It cannot.

You need to use:

```
memcpy(wData, bytes + offset, rwSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

At

```
memcpy(&wData, bytes + offset, rwSize);
```

you copy from the location of the wData pointer and to the location of the wData pointer of the new CommCommand. But you want to copy from and to the location that the pointer points to. You need to dereference. You corrupt the heap, because you have only sizeof(BYTE*) space (plus some extra, because heap blocks cannot be arbitrarily small), but you copy rwSize bytes, which is 128 bytes. What you probably meant to write is:

```
memcpy(wData, *(BYTE*)(bytes + offset), rwSize);
```

which would take use the pointer stored at bytes + offset, rather than the value of bytes + offset itself.

You also assume that your struct is tightly packed. However, C++ does not guarantee that. Is there a reason why you do not override the default copy constructor rather than write this function?

Comment: You were on the right track until you started dereferencing.

Comment: @molbdnilo I don't see my mistake. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

The memory for your struct is laid out without padding, this can be rectified by adding the macro `#pragma pack(1)` at the start of the struct and `#pragma pop()` at the end of the struct - check its syntax though.

For your struct to byte conversion, I would use something simple as:

```
template<typename T, typename IteratorForBytes>
void ConvertToBytes(const T& t, IteratorForBytes bytes, std::size_t pos = 0)
{
    std::advance(bytes, pos);
    const std::size_t length = sizeof(t);
    const uint8_t* temp = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&t);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        (*bytes) = (*temp);
        ++temp; 
        ++bytes;
    }
}
```

Where `T` is the is the struct in your case your `Command` struct and `bytes` would be the array.

```
CommIO::CommCommand command;
command.wData = new BYTE[command.rwSize];
ConvertToBytes(command, command.wData);
```

The resulting array would contain the expected `bytes` You could specify the offset as well as an extra parameter if you want to start filling your byte array from a particular location

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is here:

```
memcpy(&wData, bytes + offset, rwSize);
```

Member `wData` is a `BYTE *`, and you seem to mean to copy bytes into the space to which it points.  Instead, you are copying data into the memory where the pointer value itself is stored.  Therefore, if you copy more bytes than the size of the pointer then you will overrun its bounds and produce undefined behavior.  In any case, you are trashing the original pointer value.  You probably want this, instead:

```
memcpy(wData, bytes + offset, rwSize);
```

Additionally, although the rest of the deserialization code may be right for your actual serialization format, it is not safe to assume that it is right for the byte sequence you present to it in your test program via

```
CommIO::CommCommand command2(reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&command));
```

As detailed in comments, you are making assumptions about the layout in memory of a `CommIO::CommCommand` that C++ does not guarantee will hold.